# send email to multiple receivers from multiple senders after some delay. but got error username not hosted on this server

Tags: php, laravel, email

```
ymfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException: Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 Message rejected. captalos.com is not currently owned by sender". in /home/customer/www/talenstar.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/SmtpTransport.php:337
...
```

My code

```
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.transport' => isset($sender->driver) ? $sender->driver : 'smtp']);
                    config(['mail.mailers.smtp.host' => $sender->server]);
                    config(['mail.mailers.smtp.port' => $sender->port]);
                    config(['mail.mailers.smtp.username' => $sender->email]);
                    config(['mail.mailers.smtp.password' => $sender->password]);
                    config(['mail.mailers.smtp.encryption' => $sender->encryption]);
                    config(['mail.from.address' => $sender->email]);
                    config(['mail.from.name' => $sender->name]);
JobFormStoreAutoreplyJob::dispatch($details)->delay(now()->addSeconds(300));
```

i want to send email from multiple senders after delay...
my code is working for `dispatchNow()` but not for `dispatch($delay)`

Comment: Sounds like your host won't let you use a `from` address that doesn't belong to them. This is good security. You can always use the dynamic address as the reply-to address.

Comment: You should not use a `from` address from a mailserver that is not yours